# web ERP in django where do i start?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm a computer science student doing my bachelor's degree. i'm interested in doing an simple application like an ERP in django. I've got about a month of time don't know where do i start. please do give in  your opinion.

Comment: ERP simple?  Perhaps you should narrow that down a bit.  ERP applications (i.e. SAP) are considered to be the largest and most complex applications.

Comment: Although, Django can provide a good solution for administrative purposes. We have this built for our company related to sales, finances, human resources, production management and others.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [Django Book](http://djangobook.com/) It's an awsome introductory material.

Like @pace says (vote up!) the django tutorial is fine too (although the rest of the documentation assumes you have all the time of the world to comprehend it)

But my recommendation is take a look at python first. Not too deep, but enough to know what are they talking about in the django community. Take a look to the [Dive Into Python site](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and gt a grip on python.

There are some great books around too. Like [The Definitive Guide to Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021936X), [the Practical Django Project](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219386) and [Pro Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210478) (I'm kind of a book freak so i bought them three XD)

I think you should enjoy programming, not suffer it, I enjoy programming in Python and Django. The best thing about Django is that they have solution for common cases in wev developing, like manage the site and users, report of objects in the databases, details on every object in the database. And in the most cases you don't have to worry about SQL at all.
See if it fits you :) Happy Programming!

Answer (score 5):

The django [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) is great.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Prometeo ERP](http://code.google.com/p/prometeo-erp/). It's based on Django 1.3 and it requires only a few dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ["serpantin"](http://code.google.com/p/serpantin/), as they claim, it is a small ERP application written in Django... That will give a good start for your ERP....